# What are features of Flow, Cicerone, Fragnav, Simple-stack and when to use them?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView in my application with 3 tabs. I want to implement instagram like navigation, saving each section fragments states. Firstly I used navigation component, but it is difficult to save states of each tab (section). Then I find some libraries like flow, cicerone, fragnav, simple-stack.

What are features of flow, cicerone, fragnav, simple-stack and when to use them?

I have 2 activity and MainActivity. Mvvm architecture, dagger2, kotlin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this question a bit late, I'm the maintainer of Simple-Stack and found this question with some elaborate searches.

Anyway,

> Firstly I used navigation component, but it is difficult to save states of each tab (section).

Technically they made [this large block of code](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/da6de06e9d6a9a8f53108b1aa3f851c50e6d87c9/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt#L30-L250) that you can include and now lets you manage N navHostFragments and therefore have multiple backstacks in an app.

Whether it scales well or not I'm not sure, but it does work across rotation and process death.

> `square/flow`

Flow is dead, Square works on Workflow now.

But Flow was originally a solution to track a list of screens `[Screen1, Screen2]` and make that survive configuration changes and process death. They also allowed you to handle changes such as `[Screen1, Screen2]` -> `[Screen1, Screen2, Screen3]` in an async way (you had to call a completion callback when you were done).

It had some elements of scoping support. I tried it but couldn't make that aspect of it work.

> Cicerone

Cicerone enqueues navigation commands while there is no one registered to handle them.

Otherwise, it has some navigation commands out of the box to somewhat simplify fragment/activity navigation.

> Fragnav

FragNav was built with multi-stack support in mind. Theoretically, it tracks fragment stacks for a maximum of 5 bottom nav tabs.

> Simple-Stack

Simple-Stack was written to be a rewrite and replacement for what `square/flow` intended to do: 1 stack, asynchronous state transition support, enqueueing navigation actions while no one can handle them, persist/restore navigation state across config changes and process death.

The key difference between Flow and Simple-Stack was:

- API naming conventions (Flow had some tricky names like "Dispatcher" and "Traversal", which are in simple-stack called `StateChanger` and `StateChange`)
- simpler lifecycle integration (no more overriding `attachBaseContext`)
- all-new scoping support with ability to easily share data between screens, and persist/restore the state of these "scoped services" across process death, while getting important lifecycle callbacks about creation/destruction (kinda like ViewModels)
- completion: Flow was left as "alpha" version and is no longer maintained.

---

Flow and Simple-Stack were both built to make Single Activity apps easier to develop. Same is true of Jetpack Navigation.

Both Jetpack Navigation and Simple-Stack allows the creation of "scopes shared between screens", JN does it with navgraph-scoped viewmodels, while SS doing it with scoped services.

Multi-stack is a bit of a pain no matter what, FragNav has direct support for it out of the box, and simple-stack [has a sample for it](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/tree/6bba068fd24eeb8b379f03be1c4f81961b57def4/samples/multistack-samples/simple-stack-example-multistack-fragment/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemomultistack) (and Jetpack Navigation also [has a sample for it](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/da6de06e9d6a9a8f53108b1aa3f851c50e6d87c9/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt#L30-L250)).

---

Pick whichever tool seems like it solves the most problems for you with minimal friction.

Comment: the problem in using navigation components is that it recreates the fragment whenever you comebacks to the previous fragment. which is not very good. so does using a simple stack helps in this case ??

Comment: @vivekpanchal it doesn't recreate the fragment, it recreates its view. You can extend from Simple-Stack's `DefaultFragmentStateChanger` and override `isNotShowing`, `startShowing` and `stopShowing` like so: https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack-extensions/blob/10d6d8b09ab81df3dc28cb06dba16bc7458d93a7/example-sharedelement/src/main/java/com/example/fragmenttransitions/core/navigation/SharedElementFragmentStateChanger.java#L42-L55  and it would use show/hide instead of attach/detach and thus keep the view hierarchy alive even on forward then back navigation